# Will my Lenovo One Key Recovery work if I resize the system partition on my Ideapad Z510?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, windows-backup

I just bought a Lenovo IdeaPad Z510 laptop. Initially the hard disk contains a single partition named Windows8.1 OS (C) and  a Lenovo (D). Windows 8.1 is installed in C and the D: drive is packed with Win 8.1 Drivers and applications required for the laptop. But main problem is the size of the C partition is too huge(approx 900GB), so i want to resize it.

So, I wanted to know if the Lenovo One Key Recovery mechanism is capable of restoring(in case required) the Windows 8.1, from the hidden recovery partition, after resizing the C parition?

Comment: Is any of the below solution worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

It should.
The recovery partition simply acts as a disk image of what your system was like at the factory.
As long as you don't shrink your main drive beyond the space needed for the factory image, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on how you create partition.

"Please don't use any third party partition software, it will mess up the recovery partition and ultimately OKR will not work"

use windows shrink disk facility then there will be no problem.